# Адаптивная высота на весь экран для каждого блока

Tags: html, css

Как сделать чтобы высота бэкграунда растягивалась при увеличении высоты окна браузера? Паддингами не вариант, так как сайт с горизонтальной прокруткой, ниже есть скриншот как всё это выглядит в полноэкранном режиме, нужно чтобы бэкграунд растягивался при нажатие f11 например. Перепробывал уже все свойства у бэкграунда.

```
<article class="slider_item">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="wraper">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
                <h1>SM-Marketing</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="first-page">
                <div class="method">
                    <h2>Методика №1</h2>
                    <p class="title-p">по скоростному получению клиентов из интернета</p>
                    <p class="method-p">или <br> как с полного нуля, <br> всего через пару дней <br> начать получать первые заявки</p>
                </div>
                <div class="block-jq">
                    <div class="block-jq-item animated bounceInDown delay-0.5s"><div>как найти новых клиентов</div></div>
                    <div class="block-jq-item animated bounceInRight delay-1s"><div>как получать больше заявок</div></div>
                    <div class="block-jq-item animated bounceInUp delay-2.5s"><div>как построить систему лидогенерации</div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Ниже css

```
.slider__item 
    width: 100%
    height: 100%

.header
    background: url(../img/header_bg.png)
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    padding: 70px
    padding-bottom: 170px
    background-position: center
    background-size: 100% 100%

.wraper
    max-width: 1200px
    margin: 0 auto   

.logo
    display: flex
```

[image: Header]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.slider__item
    min-height: 100vh
```

ну и ковер, что в посте выше

Comment: немного по другому вышло, min-heigt в header добавить было и убрать все падинги с header и переместить на другие элементы.

Answer (score 0):

Для растягивание используйте `background-size: cover` также можете задать `min-height` к шапке.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Полная статья https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

А также советую прочитать: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp 
Чтобы для каждого размера экрана выдать свои классы.

Comment: Для каждого блока у меня будет отдельный бэкграунд, так что задавать через html не мой вариант. min-height добавит колесо прокрутки которое мне не нужно, так как скролл производится горизонтально.